# Is it common for only a specific folder to get corrupted on a flashdrive without malware causes

Tags: security, usb-flash-drive

I have a folder on a 64 GB Sony USB where I had hundreds of text files that I read and write to daily.  One day the entire folder suddenly became corrupt with multiple gibberish files.  All the other files on the flash drive were in tact.

I scanned my windows 10 computer with mcafee and malwarebytes without results.  I also had active protection in the background when this happened. 
This folder contained a lot of sensitive data that is why I am a little paranoid why it was only this one that got corrupted

I just want to know is it possible this was just a hardward malformation that happened to a specific flashdrive folder as opposed to an attacker gaining access to my system and specifically targeting that folder of files.

Comment: Flash drives are good at retaining data, but constant writes can degrade the memory components. Chances are that the file table that contains folder structure got corrupted when changing some attribute of a file/folder within the structure. This is common with flash drives. Your data is still there and you might be able to recover it with some tools, just don't write anything (if you haven't already) ..

Comment: What filesystem are you using on the flash drive?

Answer (score 1):

Hardware malfunction always happens to *a part* of the memory (or in case of a disk, surface area). Best case, this is on an unused portion of the material. Worst case, it happens in the middle of the area with partition information and your whole 'disk' is inaccessible.

In your case, the damage seems to have been in the part of the filesystem describing the contents of that folder (i.e. containing pointers to the physical locations of the file parts).

Comment: Is my case common or unusual?

Comment: I have no idea. To confuse things, your text asks *is it possible*. That's what I answered to. My estimate is that USB malfunction is much likelier than malware infection, but I don't know your computer knowledge and behavior (no offence).